# Why should I avoid using InheritableThreadLocal in servlets?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, thread-safety

I am using `InheritableThreadLocal` in my `Servlet` Class. So that It will available from it's child threads. Is that evil using `InheritableThreadLocal` in thread pool executors? . Such as servlet thread pool.

My Questions.

1) Why should we avoid using `InheritableThreadLocals` in servlets?

2) Is this memory leak possible in `InheritableThreadLocal`?

3) Is there any alternative for `InheritableThreadLocal`?.

4) What happens if the thread will be reused , the value stored in `threadlocal` will not be cleared?

**My Real Time Scenario**

```
public class UserAccessFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

      static final InheritableThreadLocal<String> currentRequestURI = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>();

      public void  doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp , FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException{
              String uri = request.getRequestURI();
              fc.doFilter(request, response);         
      }
}


public class MailServlet extends HttpServlet{

      @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String mailCount = req.getParameter("mailCount");

    if(mailCount != null && !"".equals(mailCount) && mailCount.matches("[0-9]+")){
        MailThread mailThread = new MailThread("xxx@gmail.com", generateToAddress(Integer.parseInt(mailCount))); //NO I18N
        Thread t = new Thread(mailThread);
        t.start();
    }

    resp.getWriter().println("Mail Servlet.............."); //NO I18N

}              

}

class MailThread implements Runnable{

private String from;
private String to;

public MailThread(String from , String to){
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    sendMail();
}

    public void sendMail(){
        //I want this uri from child threads. I can't pass this value to this constructor.
        String uri = currentRequestURI.get();
        //Do Mail Operations
    }


}
```

Filter  --> Servlet A --> Child Thread ---> Mail Thread (Here I am getting the value setted in filter) .

Answer (score 15):

> Why should we avoid using InheritableThreadLocals in servlets?

They represent a potential path for leaking *information* from one request to another.  The "problem" is that requests are handled by a pool of threads.  When on request is completed, the next request that a thread handles is likely to be for a different user.  But if you forget to clear the thread local state on finishing the first request, there is a potential that it might be used by the second one.

> Is a memory leak possible in InheritableThreadLocal?

Yes ... sort of.  If we assume that the worker pool is bounded, the thread local state of any thread is likely to be overwritten, clearing the memory leak.  At worst the problem is a bounded memory leak ... bounded by the number of threads in the pool.

The information leakage problem is more concerning.

> Is there any alternative for InheritableThreadLocal?

Setting attributes in the request or response object is better.

> What happens if the thread will be reused, the value stored in threadlocal will not be cleared.

It won't be cleared.  THAT is the problem!

Comment: I am resetting the value on `filter` then it's not a problem?

Comment: It depends exactly when the value is reset ... and whether you can guarantee that it will *always* be reset.

Comment: Isn't there a line missing in the `UserAccessFilter` that should be setting the value?  That value is then inherited when the thread is created in the servlet after which it can be set to any value you want by the request thread, the value seen be the created thread will be unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works, the `MailThread` *inherits* the value of `currentRequestURI` when it is created.

But the `UserAccessFilter` and the `java.lang.InheritableThreadLocal` just serve to confuse what the code is trying to do, which is the evil part.

What's wrong changing the constructor of `MailThread` so that you can pass the request URI from the `MailServlet` like this:

```
MailThread mailThread = new MailThread("xxx@gmail.com", generateToAddress(Integer.parseInt(mailCount)), req.getRequestURI());
```

Then you have no need for a thread local, you don't need the filter and the code is clearer.

Comment: I can't pass the requestURI to `MailThread`. Here I am posting the sample scenario.

Comment: Why can you pass the requestURI to `MailThread`, you've got the `HttpServletRequest` in the `doGet` method?

Comment: Yeah, But I can't restrict  to send the request uri to send the email. It can be used by other members.

Comment: What do you mean 'other members'?

Comment: It's like writing an third party api. This can be used my colleagues to  send an mail from my code. I am restricting the sendMail based on the requestURI. If I give the constructor to pass requestURI. They might pass an invalid uri.

Comment: How are your colleagues going to use your code?  If their code just sends a request to your servlet then the `requestURI` is just going to be that of your servlet.  If they're going to use the `MailThread` class then that relies on them have set the `requestURI` in the thread local correctly.  The bottom line is mistakes can always be made, convoluted schemes like this only increase the likelihood of a mistake, which is why at the end of the day, you have a test cycle.