# What happen when tomcat worker threads reuse?

Tags: java, tomcat, inheritable-thread-local

I use a InheritableThreadLocal in each tomcat requests to store some information , codes like those:

```
public class ThreadLocalUtils {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("httpClientLogLogger");


    private static ThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>> threadLocal = new InheritableThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>>() {
        public Map<String, Object> initialValue() {
            logger.info("threadname:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, Object> childValue(Map<String, Object> parentValue) {
            logger.info("threadname2:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return parentValue;
        }
    };

    public static void set(String key, Object value) {
        Map<String, Object> map = threadLocal.get();
        map.put(key, value);
        threadLocal.set(map);
    }

    public static Object get(String key) {
        return threadLocal.get().get(key);
    }
}
```

Then I found some threads were modified a same InheritableThreadLocal variable , so i printed some logs in set and get methods , logs printed like those , and each record wrote in each http request :

```
2021-06-29 11:47:33,785 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-10] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-10
2021-06-29 11:47:34,014 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.childValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:22)] [http-bio-8965-exec-10] [INFO]-threadname2:http-bio-8965-exec-10
2021-06-29 11:47:34,027 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-1] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-1
2021-06-29 11:47:34,355 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-3] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-3
2021-06-29 11:47:34,443 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-2] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-2
2021-06-29 11:47:34,617 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-6] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-6
2021-06-29 11:47:34,794 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-4] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-4
2021-06-29 11:47:34,905 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-8] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-8
2021-06-29 11:47:35,196 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-7] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-7
2021-06-29 11:47:35,483 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-9] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-9
2021-06-29 11:47:35,496 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-11] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-11
2021-06-29 11:47:35,757 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-5] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-5
2021-06-29 11:47:36,126 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-13] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-13
2021-06-29 11:47:37,266 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-12] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-12
2021-06-29 11:47:38,216 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-14] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-14
2021-06-29 11:47:39,013 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:15)] [http-bio-8965-exec-16] [INFO]-threadname:http-bio-8965-exec-16
2021-06-29 11:47:39,151 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.childValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:22)] [http-bio-8965-exec-13] [INFO]-threadname2:http-bio-8965-exec-13
```

Threads named "http-bio-8965-exec-10" and  "http-bio-8965-exec-13" run into both initialValue() and childValue(Map<String, Object> parentValue) methods.

How is that possible , What happen when tomcat worker threads reuse?

Update：
I added stackTrace log into childValue() method and found something new:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, Object> childValue(Map<String, Object> parentValue) {
    logger.info("threadname2:"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Id:"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    logger.info("threadname2:"+ JSON.toJSONString(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()));
    return parentValue;
}
```

logs:

```
2021-06-29 20:26:48,656 [com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1.childValue(ThreadLocalUtils.java:23)] [http-bio-8965-exec-4] [INFO]-threadname2:[{"className":"java.lang.Thread","fileName":"Thread.java","lineNumber":1589,"methodName":"getStackTrace","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1","fileName":"ThreadLocalUtils.java","lineNumber":23,"methodName":"childValue","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"com.x.common.util.ThreadLocalUtils$1","fileName":"ThreadLocalUtils.java","lineNumber":14,"methodName":"childValue","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap","fileName":"ThreadLocal.java","lineNumber":353,"methodName":"<init>","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap","fileName":"ThreadLocal.java","lineNumber":261,"methodName":"<init>","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.lang.ThreadLocal","fileName":"ThreadLocal.java","lineNumber":236,"methodName":"createInheritedMap","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.lang.Thread","fileName":"Thread.java","lineNumber":416,"methodName":"init","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.lang.Thread","fileName":"Thread.java","lineNumber":349,"methodName":"init","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.lang.Thread","fileName":"Thread.java","lineNumber":596,"methodName":"<init>","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread","fileName":"TaskThread.java","lineNumber":32,"methodName":"<init>","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThreadFactory","fileName":"TaskThreadFactory.java","lineNumber":42,"methodName":"newThread","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker","fileName":"ThreadPoolExecutor.java","lineNumber":610,"methodName":"<init>","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor","fileName":"ThreadPoolExecutor.java","lineNumber":924,"methodName":"addWorker","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor","fileName":"ThreadPoolExecutor.java","lineNumber":1371,"methodName":"execute","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor","fileName":"ThreadPoolExecutor.java","lineNumber":162,"methodName":"execute","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor","fileName":"ThreadPoolExecutor.java","lineNumber":142,"methodName":"execute","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor","fileName":"JIoEndpoint.java","lineNumber":344,"methodName":"run","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor","fileName":"ThreadPoolExecutor.java","lineNumber":1145,"methodName":"runWorker","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker","fileName":"ThreadPoolExecutor.java","lineNumber":615,"methodName":"run","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable","fileName":"TaskThread.java","lineNumber":61,"methodName":"run","nativeMethod":false},{"className":"java.lang.Thread","fileName":"Thread.java","lineNumber":745,"methodName":"run","nativeMethod":false}]
```

I am using tomcat 7.0.54 ,

```
{
    "className": "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor",
    "fileName": "JIoEndpoint.java",
    "lineNumber": 344,
    "methodName": "run",
    "nativeMethod": false
}
```

that code create a new thread,
codes:

```
getExecutor().execute(new SocketProcessor(socket, SocketStatus.OPEN_READ));
```

Comment: *"How is that possible"* I'm confused about your confusion. You specifically use `InheritableThreadLocal` so the value stored in the ThreadLocal can be copied to (shared with) a child thread. Thread #10 creates a child thread, so it calls the `childValue()`, which is what it is supposed to do. What exactly about that is confusing you?

Comment: The fact that you give the non-concurrent `HashMap` object directly to the child thread is an error in your code that will lead to race conditions and corrupt data structures.

Comment: Will tomcat worker thread create a child worker thread and give a same name? I haven't create a child thread  in my own code.

Comment: Worker threads will most likely be pooled, i.e. Tomcat won't create new threads all the time but spin up as many as needed (normally dependent on number of cores etc.) and those then work on tasks provided to them. So if 2 tasks (e.g. requests) are handled by the same worker thread they will have access to the same ThreadLocals.

Comment: According to this , It shouldn't run into childValue() method.

Comment: 1) Why do you believe the child thread being created is a Tomcat worker thread? It could easily be a thread created by your code, or whatever framework you use, not by Tomcat. --- 2) Why do you believe the child thread is named the same as the parent thread? Asked differently, why do you believe that it is the child thread that calls `childValue(...)`? The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html#childValue-T-) specifically says otherwise: *"This method is **called from within the parent thread** before the child is started."*

Comment: Well, you could log the stacktrace and see where exactly those methods are being called and why (Tomcat is open source so it should be possible to get the sources for the version you're using, e.g. here: http://tomcat.apache.org/source.html). Here's some general information on Tomcat threads: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/tomcat-architecture-and-performance/#requests-and-worker-threads

Comment: @Thomas Most likely, OP won't even need the Tomcat source code, because the entire question is based on a wild assumption that the child thread being created is a new Tomcat worker thread. There is no evidence of that. It could be a Java 8 parallel stream thread. It could be a cleanup thread created on first use of a database connection pool. Your idea of checking the call stack from the `childValue(...)` method is great, since it should show who called the thread `start()` method.

Comment: [Why should I avoid using InheritableThreadLocal in servlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14498906/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas I had misunderstand on the childValue(...) method. How can I find where the thread has been created ?My project has imported a lot dependencies.

Comment: @PowerDebugger Get rid of `InheritableThreadLocal` and all your problems go away. In a webapp, you really shouldn't be creating new threads yourself, and if you do, they surely shouldn't share thread-locals. You should pass any necessary data to the new thread directly, and have it initialize it's own threadlocal, if needed. The thread landscape of a webapp is just too convoluted to use `InheritableThreadLocal`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I find the answer.Under Http 1.1 tomcat(my version is 7.0.54) worker thread won't close after return a response , It will create a new thread into pool to handle next http1.1 request.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint
        @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean launch = false;
        synchronized (socket) {
            try {
                SocketState state = SocketState.OPEN;

                try {
                    // SSL handshake
                    serverSocketFactory.handshake(socket.getSocket());
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    ExceptionUtils.handleThrowable(t);
                    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        log.debug(sm.getString("endpoint.err.handshake"), t);
                    }
                    // Tell to close the socket
                    state = SocketState.CLOSED;
                }

                if ((state != SocketState.CLOSED)) {
                    if (status == null) {
                        state = handler.process(socket, SocketStatus.OPEN_READ);
                    } else {
                        state = handler.process(socket,status);
                    }
                }
                if (state == SocketState.CLOSED) {
                    // Close socket
                    if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
                        log.trace("Closing socket:"+socket);
                    }
                    countDownConnection();
                    try {
                        socket.getSocket().close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // Ignore
                    }
                } else if (state == SocketState.OPEN ||
                        state == SocketState.UPGRADING ||
                        state == SocketState.UPGRADING_TOMCAT  ||
                        state == SocketState.UPGRADED){
                    socket.setKeptAlive(true);
                    socket.access();
                    launch = true;
                } else if (state == SocketState.LONG) {
                    socket.access();
                    waitingRequests.add(socket);
                }
            } finally {
                if (launch) {
                    try {
                        //http 1.1 will do
                        getExecutor().execute(new SocketProcessor(socket, SocketStatus.OPEN_READ));
                    } catch (RejectedExecutionException x) {
                        log.warn("Socket reprocessing request was rejected for:"+socket,x);
                        try {
                            //unable to handle connection at this time
                            handler.process(socket, SocketStatus.DISCONNECT);
                        } finally {
                            countDownConnection();
                        }


                    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                        if (running) {
                            log.error(sm.getString("endpoint.launch.fail"),
                                    npe);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        socket = null;
        // Finish up this request
    }

}
```